# How do I make thin edges much more thicker without messing the inside of the object?

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

So I have here this object which looks like a cabinet. The problem is that the edge is too thin, which makes it unrealistic.

A solution I have tried is to use the solidify modifier but unfortunately it didn't go as well as expected. Here are it's results; **BEFORE AND AFTER**

Before:

Inside of the object:

[image]

Edges of the object:

[image]

After applying the Solidify modifier:

Inside the object:

[image]

Edges of the object:

[image]

You could even see the off scaling of the edges.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the *Mode > Complex*, *Thickness Mode > Constraints*, it seems to work fine:

[image]